# Namespace with the same name as type alias in the same file

Tags: typescript

I've come across a pattern that can be summarized as:

```js
export namespace Foo {
    export enum Bar {}
}
export type Foo = Omit<typeof Foo, 'Bar'>
```

(Original code [here](https://github.com/rokoroku/react-redux-typescript-boilerplate/blob/master/src/app/actions/todos.ts#L24).)
With my rudimentary understanding of typescript, what I *think* this is doing is:

1. declaring a namespace `Foo`
2. Taking `typeof Foo` to create a type from that namespace.
3. Omitting `Bar` from the type created in 2, and aliasing this type to identifier `Foo`.

So far so good, I *think*, but please correct me if I'm wrong. At this point things get into magic territory for me. This is because when `Foo` is imported from another file, somehow magically the namespace `Foo` is imported, rather than the type alias `Foo`. My questions are:

1. Does the second file import the right `Foo` due to type inference magic or is there something else going on here that I should know?
2. Back to the original file declaring the two `Foo`s, is it at all weird that we have two things with the same name without a name collision? Is the collision avoided by the fact that namespaces are objects and type aliases are types?
3. Is this a common pattern in TypeScript? Is it a good pattern? Should I be writing code like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your thinking is correct with regards to what the code is doing.

1. Yes, the compiler infers whether it refers to the type alias or the namespace based on the usage.

For example: https://github.com/rokoroku/react-redux-typescript-boilerplate/blob/master/src/app/components/TodoList/index.tsx#L10

Here, `TodoActions` is used as a type, so the compiler knows that it refers to the exported type alias.

Another example: https://github.com/rokoroku/react-redux-typescript-boilerplate/blob/master/src/app/reducers/todos.ts#L16

Here, `TodoActions.Type.ADD_TODO` is used to create a property, so the compiler, again, knows that it refers to the namespace.

You can actually see this if you hover over the identifier in VS Code:

[image: Type]

[image: Namespace]

2. and 3.) It can be a little confusing at first, but this is intended behavior. I personally would avoid it though, as it can cause unnecessary confusion.

The following article explains the exact question you have: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/deep-dive.html